# C Builder remove border on FMX ImageControl

Tags: c++builder, firemonkey

I'm displaying a bitmap image on my Firemoney desktop form using an ImageControl in RAD Studio XE3.  The image displays correctly but has a border around it.  The image has a white background and is being displayed on a white panel.

Is it possible to remove this border?

Comment: Can you not use the `TImage` component from the 'Shapes' component tab?

Comment: Perfect, that does exactly what I want!  How do I mark your response as an answer?

Comment: I've added it as an answer. Thanks :)

Answer (score 0):

Use the `TImage` control in the 'Shapes' component tab.

Comment: This doesn't exist anymore in C++ Builder 10.3.3 (and higher probably)